# Python Flask Redirect

Tags: python, flask

```
def check():
  if 3>2:
     return redirect(url_for('control'))

@app.route('/reason', methods=['GET','POST'])
def reason():
  check()
  return render_template('reason.html')

@app.route('/control', methods=['GET','POST']
def control():
 return render_template('control.html')
```

I have two html files (control.html and reason.html). the code loads reason.html page first and receives user input using POST method then after doing certain checks, I want to reload control.html.

the problem is I am not able to load control.html

Comment: `reason()` needs to `return check()`, not just call it and then throw away the redirect response it returned.

Comment: @jasonharper
my bad.. it actually returns reason.html
I have edited the question

Comment: @ShishayGhebrehiwet What @jasonharper is talking about is that you should actually use the return value of `check()`, in fact if there is a return value other than `None`, you want to return it. As it is, you are just ignoring it, and returning `reason.html` all the time.

Comment: @bgse
  check() doesn't return anything, except loading another html page.
but reason() has to load reason.html, that's where I grab user input and send it to check(). check() checks certain thing and if true returns a control.html page.
thanks

Comment: @ShishayGhebrehiwet You seem to be assuming that `return redirect(...)` will cause a redirect. This is not the case, in fact it just returns a response with a redirect. You need to return this response in your view function `reason()` if you actually want a redirect.

Comment: @bgse thanks for your advise, what am trying to achieve is to load the reason() first and grab user input and will pass it another function (in this case check()) and after checking certain things, I wanna load another function that loads a new page. 
I will edit my question again.

Comment: @bgse   I will beg your pardon as I am a beginner for python, but If it really helps you to understand my problem, I have edited the question
thanks

Comment: I do understand the problem, look at the answer from @Rob, that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the return value from `check()`. Consequently, the object that will signal a redirect is simply lost.

You should inspect the return value from `check()` and either return that result, or the `'reason.html'` result:

```
# UNTESTED
@app.route('/reason', methods=['GET','POST'])
def reason():
  check_result = check()
  if check_result:
     return check_result
  return render_template('reason.html')
```

On a related note, your `check()` has two return paths. One explicitly invokes `return`, the other implicitly returns `None` as it falls off the end of the function. This is perfectly legal, but confusing stylistically. Try this:

```
def check():
  if 3>2:
     return redirect(url_for('control'))
  return None
```

Perhaps a more understandable code arrangement would be to have `check` limit its responsibilities to simply checking and reporting the result; then `reason()` can be responsible for whatever page is displayed, like so:

```
#UNTESTED
def check():
  if 3>2:
     return True
  return False

# UNTESTED
@app.route('/reason', methods=['GET','POST'])
def reason():
  if check():
     return redirect(url_for('control'))
  return render_template('reason.html')
```

Comment: Even less confusing would probably be just returning truthy/falsy depending on the actual check performed, and having `if check(): return redirect(...)` in the view function itself, at least in this simple case with only one possible redirect target.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to edit if I missed what you were saying.

Comment: @Robᵩ 
thank you guys, it works perfectly... I really appreciate your effort 
cheers